# How to determine the max precision for double

Tags: java, floating-point, double, precision

I am trying to determine what the maximum precision for a double is. In the comments for the accepted answer in this link [Retain precision with double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java) @PeterLawrey states max precision in 15.

How do you determine this ?

Comment: Did you look at the [linked wiki in the duplicate question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)? Java uses IEEE 754 floating-point doubles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> @PeterLawrey states max precision in 15.

That's actually not what he stated at all. What he stated was:

> double has 15 decimal places of accuracy

and he is wrong. They have 15 decimal *digits* of accuracy.

The number of decimal digits in any number is given by its log to the base 10. 15 is the floor value of log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>53</sup>-1), where 53 is the number of bits of mantissa (including the implied bit), as described in the Javadoc and IEEE 754, and 2<sup>53</sup>-1 is therefore the maximum possible mantissa value. The actual value is 15.954589770191003298111788092734 to the limits of the Windows calculator.

He is quite wrong to describe it as 'decimal places of accuracy'. A `double` has 15 decimal *digits* of accuracy *if they are all before the decimal point.* For numbers with fractional parts you can get many more than 15 digits in the decimal representation, because of the incommensurability of decimal and binary fractions.

Comment: thanks clarifies it a bit. However does 2^53 max mantissa value imply 15 digits ?

Comment: The number of decimal digits in any number is given by its log to the base 10.

Comment: The "straight logarithm argument" only applies to integers, which is perhaps what you're saying in your last paragraph. For floating-point you have to do a derivation like I do here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/ . For doubles you get the same answer (15); for floats, log_10(2^24-1) is approx 7.22, but the max precision is 6. (Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688422/is-the-most-significant-decimal-digits-precision-that-can-be-converted-to-binary .)

Comment: @RickRegan why is the the max precision 6 and not & for floats ?

Comment: @ShivamSinha I think that is explained in the two links in my comment.

Comment: As a follow up to my prior comment...I wrote an article specifically addressing the issue: http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/ @ShivamSinha

Answer (score 2):

Run this code, and see where it stops

```
public class FindPrecisionDouble {
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 0.5;
    double epsilon = 0;
    int nb_iter = 0;
    while ((nb_iter < 1000) && (x != y)) {
        System.out.println(x-y);
        epsilon = Math.abs(x-y);
        y = ( x + y ) * 0.5;
    }
    final double prec_decimal = - Math.log(epsilon) / Math.log(10.0);
    final double prec_binary = - Math.log(epsilon) / Math.log(2.0);
    System.out.print("On this machine, for the 'double' type, ");
    System.out.print("epsilon = " );
    System.out.println( epsilon );
    System.out.print("The decimal precision is " );
    System.out.print( prec_decimal );
    System.out.println(" digits" );
    System.out.print("The binary precision is " );
    System.out.print( prec_binary );
    System.out.println(" bits" );
  }
}
```

Variable `y` becomes the smallest value different than `1.0`.  On my computer (Mac Intel Core i5), it stops at `1.1102...E-16`.  It then prints the precision (in decimal and in binary).

As stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon, floating-point precision can be estimated with the epsilon value.
It is "the smallest number that, when added to one, yields a result different from one" (I did a small variation: 1-e instead of 1+e, but the logic is the same)

I'll explain in decimal: if you have a 4-decimals precision, you can express 1.0000 - 0.0001, but you cannot express the number 1.00000-0.00001 (you lack the 5th decimal). In this example, with a 4-decimals precision, the epsilon is 0.0001. The epsilon directly measures the floating-point precision. Just transpose to binary.

**Edit** Your question asked "How to determine...".  The answer you were searching were more an explanation of than a way to determine precision (with the answer you accepted).  Anyways, for other people, running this code on a machine will determine the precision for the "double" type.

Comment: It tries to find the epsilon value, which is related to the floating-point precision. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon (look at the binary64 line in the table)

Comment: He is asking about the floating-point precision itself, not the epsilon, and he is specifically asking about the value 15, which you haven't addressed at all.

Comment: I'll explain in decimal: if you have a 4-decimals precision, you can express `1.0000 - 0.0001`, but you cannot express the number `1.00000-0.00001`.   In this example, with a 4-decimals precision, the epsilon is 0.0001.  The epsilon **directly** measures the floating-point precision.  Just transpose to binary.   (note: the exponent of my result is `1.11E-16` tells that the precision is about 15 digits)

Comment: You should explain all that in your answer, but the number of digits in a decimal fraction tells you exactly nothing. The one you printed has 17 decimal digits.

Comment: The answer is **not** the number of decimals digits it prints.  The answer is the exponent of the value (-16).  I'll remove some digits to remove the confusion.

Comment: Again, you needed to explain that in your answer. But all you're providing is an iterative solution to an analytic problem, poorly explained.

Answer (score -1):

You could also "measure" it directly:

```
for(double d = 1 ; d > 0 ; d/=2) System.out.println(d);
```

The idea of this code is to reach the smallest number with one single bit. So you start with `1` (which only has 1 bit) and divide by two (which shifts bits towards the right in binary) until you reach the last bit. The last number printed by this loop is:

> 4.9E-324

Comment: How does that show that doubles have 15 digits precision?

Comment: The smallest value representable in a double has nothing whatsoever to do with its maximum precision. One is a function of the exponent width, the other of the mantissa width.

Answer (score -1):

The max precision of `double` of is the first value greater than 0. According Double's Javadoc, this number is represented by [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE). You can output it as follows:

```
BigDecimal doubleMinVal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(doubleMinVal.toPlainString());
System.out.println(doubleMinVal.toString());
```

See [this IDEOne program](http://ideone.com/7FkVGC) for an example.

Comment: I don't think that's true. I believe the OP wants to know the exact number of significant figures that are meaningful in a double. The smallest possible (absolute) double value is just the one with the largest negative exponential portion and the smallest number portion.

Comment: You are confusing precision with range, like several other answers here.