# Format a double to 6 decimal places precision

Tags: java, precision, number-formatting

I want to format a double value to 6 places precision without rounding.

expected value after format to 6 decimal places

```
20790123833965.960938
```

I have tried using decimal format

```
   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");
   System.out.println(formatter.format(hashValue) );
```

And i got this

```
20790123833965.960000
```

Comment: The result is reasonable, a `double` can only provide 15 to 16 decimal digits precision.

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: Related: [How to determine the max precision for double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344758/how-to-determine-the-max-precision-for-double)

Comment: For extra precision, use `BigDecimal`:
`BigDecimal hashValue = new BigDecimal("20790123833965.960938123");` Then it will produce the expected output.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful? If not, please tell ud what you’re still missing, we’re still here to help. If one was, please remember to accept the most helpful one. Thx.

Answer (score 11):

As [@Benoit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6271180/benoit) already said in a comment, to keep the full precision of your number, you need a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
BigDecimal hashValue = new BigDecimal("20790123833965.960938");
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");
System.out.println(formatter.format(hashValue));
```

Output:

> 20790123833965.960938

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, it will work.

```
public class JavaFormatter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BigDecimal hashValue = new BigDecimal("20790123833965.960938");     
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(hashValue));
    }
}
```